# Change GPS UTC time in a Mediatek based android system

Tags: android, gps, utc

In most (more likely all) Mediatek mtk6592 phones (and also older models), There is a bug related to GPS UTC time. 
the bug causes the GPS to report **WRONG** UTC time by an offset of *exactly 1 hour*.
That means that the sky view (which is the number and position of satellites currently visible) is **shifted by one hour** and that means that the phone is trying to connect to satellites that aren't there and even worst, it IGNORES satellites that are there!
Fixing this small issue will improve GPS in all Mediatek phones.
BTW, I discovered this bug and informed Mediatek but got no reply to date.

The question is whether Android can be fixed to insert a 1 hour shift to the GPS UTC time a thus fixing the problem.

Comment: There's no programming question here-  your answer either requires you to install a custom ROM without the bug, or write your own version of apps that account for it.  Given the tiny marketshare, you're better off looking for that custom rom, or at least a custom driver somewhere.

Comment: There is no ROM in existence without the bug because no one (presumably) knows about this bug yet.  The programming question here is in fact: "where is the GPS location calculated, in the android ROM or inside the SoC?" because if it is internal to the SoC, no ROM modification will be able to help.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt that your information is correct!
The GPS chip receives the time from the satellites in GPS Time base, which is some seconds differet from UTC (about 17 or 18s), then after some minutes the sattelites also send the GPS time to UTC offset, for better display to the end user.

I am very sure that the chip does his work correct, otherwise nothing would work.
The time has to be correct to about nanos seconds!
If there is realy an UTC time offset, then it is in the phone or software API.
But this has nothing to do with the quality of the location, because again:

inside the GPS chip everything will work!

Probably there is an internal API like in iOS and android that replaces the location timestamps received from the GPS chip, to match the current time zone, and to match the offset from the phone time to the real time (by GPS UTC) (if the user has manualy set the time).
And this internal time replacement might fail.

Event if there would be a bug in the chip, under no circumstances you could externaly correct that time bug! GPS chips allow to set the current time, but this feature is for faster speed up of initial time calculation. In practise this does only work if the time set is extremly precise.

Comment: Unfortunately that is not the case. There is a bug in the UTC that has nothing to do with the time zone. I got feedback from many people around the world and all of them report the same 1 hour offset.

Comment: might be, but again this has nothing to do with the GPS chip and its location finding. utc is only for external comfort, the chip uses GPS time, not utc! are you able to communicate directly with the chip via nmea protocol? do you see the wrong time in the NMEA messages?

Comment: forwarded comment from user rox: "I can confirm that there is a relation between android time zone and gps utc time displayed in some mobile phones. The bug of 1 hour difference actually exists even it may not be related to the gps hardware. Gps Utc time should never change whatever time zone is set on the mobile."